# Aarch64 conditional jump compilation

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, arm64, cpu-registers

I have the following code [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/rr3eKqsMz) using clang:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

int f(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
    int32_t result;
    if (a < 10) {
        result = a + b;
    } else {
        result = a * b;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {;
  int res = f(5, 9);
  if (res > 5) {
    return res;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now the assembly generated for the `if (a < 10)` is as follows:

```
 subs w8, w8, #10
 cset w8, ge
 tbnz w8, #0, .LBB0_2
 ...

 .LBB0_1:
  ...
  add w8, w8, w9
  ...

 .LBB0_2:
  ...
  mul w8, w8, w9
```

We can see that the branch is going to the addition block when `w8 = 0`.
`w8` is set to `0` when the condition `ge` is not satisfied by the `cset` instruction.
`ge` condition is satisfied when flags `N` (negative) and `V` (overflow) are equal.
Both flags are set by the last flags setting instruction which is the `subs` instruction.

Now what I don't understand about this compiled assembly output is why bother with the `ge` condition in the `cset` instruction and not use something like the `pl` condition. Why would we want the extra check of is `w8` is less than min signed 32 int, how does it translates to the original high level compiled code we provided?

I realized my original question didn't fully represent my doubts on this compilation, I'm also fully aware I didn't compile with optimization, I did it on purpose to achieve the following compiled assembly.

My main concern with this is what if a say `a` is set to `-2147483643`, now the result is overflowing because it'll be less than `-2^31` so it'll become positive, and so the negative flag won't be set, so we have a situation where `N != V` yet by the high level code `-2147483643` is indeed less than `10`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/s7n6csnav

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)

Comment: Indeed, that's overly complex for no benefit, IDK why Clang wouldn't just `cmp w8, #10` / `b.ge`.  (`b.pl` makes no sense, as you say on signed overflow the sign of the result can be different from the signed less-than condition.  `b.ge` and `b.lt` check both the Negative and oVerflow flags for that reason.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't optimized because you didn't turn on optimizations. The inefficiency you ask about is not found with any amounts of optimizations enabled (e.g. `-O3`).

Comment: OP has even disabled them intentionally

Comment: I did it on purpose to achieve the desired output assembly, I edited my question to give an example of something I'm probably wrong about, but it confuses me as to how the jump is taken in a specific case

Comment: Your question (still) asks "why bother" doing it one way instead of another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience, but I believe

```
subs w8, w8, #10
cset w8, ge
tbnz w8, #0, .LBB0_2
```

means if w8 >= 10 goto LBBO_2

because `subs w8, w8, #10` sets flag true when w8 is greater than or same as 10

Comment: @ikegami, Thank you for your kindness.